# React Native - Sort array based off words

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting

Hey guys i have the following array:

```
Array [
    Object {
        "data": "Cat Man",
        "id": "1",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Bat Girl",
        "id": "2",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Mr Penguin",
        "id": "3",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Cheeky Cheetah",
        "id": "4",
    },
]
```

I am going to take the users input in the form of a search bar, how can i sort the array based off the users input.

So lets say the user inputs

```
Bat g
```

the array would be sorted to:

```
Array [
    Object {
        "data": "Bat Girl",
        "id": "2",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Cat Man",
        "id": "1",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Mr Penguin",
        "id": "3",
    },
    Object {
        "data": "Cheeky Cheetah",
        "id": "4",
    },
]
```

How can I achieve this?

I have been searching around the array sort function:

```
Array.prototype.sort()
```

However I have only seen how to sort based off number comparisons I have never seen an array sorted based off string values like a search. Please could someone help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is function to search data using string text.

```
const searchItem = txt => {
    let text = txt.toLowerCase();

    let tracks = dataArray;

    let filterTracks = tracks.filter(item => {
      if (item.data.toLowerCase().match(text)) {
        return item;
      }
    });

    console.log('filterTracks', filterTracks);
  };
```

**Array Should be like this**

```
var dataArray = [
  {
    data: 'Cat Man',
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    data: 'Bat Girl',
    id: '2',
  },
  {
    data: 'Mr Penguin',
    id: '3',
  },
  {
    data: 'Cheeky Cheetah',
    id: '4',
  },
];
```